# Asynchronous python function calls, keep rescheduling functions in asyncio.gather without waiting for longest running task

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

So currently i have asynchronous python code (using asyncio) that looks like this:

```
while datetime.now() < time_limit:
  last_start_run_time = datetime.now()
  result = await asyncio.gather(
    *(
      get_output(output_source)
    )
    for output_source in output_sources
  )
  for output in res:
    output_dict.update(my_output_dict)
  if (datetime.now() - last_start_run_time).seconds < upper_bound_wait:
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
```

The problem with this code is that it always waits for the longest running **get_output** call to call the function again for all output sources.

I am wondering how can i rewrite this code in a way that calls each **get_output** call for each **output_source** as soon as it had finished it's earlier run (if it is within the **upper_bound_wait** ), i would also like the delay to be per **get_output** function call rather than after it finishes all of them.

How can this be achieved used asyncio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion: move all your logic to a coroutine and create the tasks in a simple loop.  each task will decide for itself when to delay, when to repeat, and when to exit.

```
async def get_output_repeatable(upper_bound_wait, output_source):
    while datetime.now() < time_limit:
        last_start_run_time = datetime.now()
        output_dict.update(await get_output(output_source))
        if (datetime.now() - last_start_run_time).seconds < upper_bound_wait:
            await asyncio.sleep(delay)

def run_them_all():            
  for output_source in output_sources:
      asyncio.create_task(get_output_repeatedly(upper_bound_wait, output_source))
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of this approach. I think you need to update `last_start_run_time` at the end of each `while` iteration. Also, `get_output_source` should be `get_output`.

Comment: Ah yes, this is a great solution, as the other person who answered said it only needs to update the last_start_run_time and then it's golden.

Comment: @user4815162342 Right you are about the get_output thing, now fixed.  As for the last_start_run_time, you have to be careful since the function run_them_all() is not an async def; it will return immediately.  When you call it again you will launch a new set of tasks, whether the old ones have finished or not.   I wasn't sure about the application requirements so I didn't address that issue.

Comment: I think you still need to re-set `last_start_run_time` before each re-start, right (i.e. at the end of each `while` iteration)? Otherwise it wouldn't be **last** start_run_time, but **first**. That's what "per-output-source delay" part of the requirements refers to.

Comment: As the other user said, last_start_run_time doesn't need to be be passed as a parameter just initialize it in the while loop ahead of each call to get_output

Comment: Duh, yes now I get what you are saying.  Edited again. The only purpose of last_start_run_time is to avoid starting the task again too quickly.  With the changes you guys are suggesting, the program will not restart any given update until at least "delay" seconds have passed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `asyncio.wait` with `FIRST_COMPLETED` in a loop. You'll need to store the original source somewhere, e.g. on the future/task objects which are both passed to and returned from `asyncio.wait`. That way the loop can reinvoke `get_output` with the same source to reschedule it. Likewise, to make the delay per-`get_output`-invocation, you'll need to store the start time of each previous invocation, probably also on the future/task. For example (untested):

```py
async def delayed_run(aw):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    return await aw

async def run_sources(output_sources, time_limit, upper_bound_wait):
    output_dict = {}

    pending = set()
    for output_source in output_sources:
        fut = asyncio.create_task(get_output(output_source))
        fut.my_start_time = time.time()
        fut.my_source = output_source
        pending.add(fut)

    while pending and time.time() < time_limit:
        done, pending = await asyncio.wait(
            pending, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED,
            timeout=time_limit - time.time())

        for done_fut in done:
            output_dict.update(done_fut.result())
            new_coro = get_output(done_fut.my_source)
            if time.time() - done_fut.my_start_time < upper_bound_wait:
                new_coro = delayed_run(new_coro)
            new_fut = asyncio.create_task(new_coro)
            new_fut.my_start_time = time.time()
            new_fut.my_source = done_fut.my_source
            pending.add(new_fut)

    return output_dict
```

Comment: I am really confused about what the code is doing, is there some resource that explains this design pattern ? also where is the loop through the different output sources, here i only see 1 call to get_output(output_source) but in my asyncio.gather call getoutput(output_source) is called asynchronously for each output source.

Comment: Assume getoutput reads and parses a file, and an output_source is just a file for example, what would it look like in this case, how would it need to change to work with your code, also i see calls to something like my_factory, i don't see it defined ? i am very confused !

Comment: @user2968505 *is there some resource that explains this design pattern?* - no, the code was custom-written for the use case as I understood it from your description. *Assume getoutput reads and parses a file, and an output_source is just a file for example* - file wouldn't work because, as you are surely aware, Python file IO is not async. *here i only see 1 call to get_output(output_source)* - that is a result of a combination of an error in your code (the call to `gather` doesn't appear correct) and a misreading on my part. I'll edit the answer to add an example of `get_output`.

Comment: @user2968505 I've now edited the answer to omit the "factory" idea that was confusing you. The code now directly calls `get_output` with the appropriate source. It still has to store the original source on the future object (this time into `my_source`, which was formerly `my_factory`), so it knows how to create the next one once the current one completes.